# xamarin.UITest vs calabash

Tags: xamarin-test-cloud

have an cross platform shared code application(xamarin.ios) developed in xamarin studio.Need to perform testing which framework is better xamarin.UITest or calabash framework let me know pros and corns of each framework?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to read [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/choosing-a-framework/).

Calabash is Ruby and UITest is C# (NUnit) it's up to you to choose one of them depend on which is more convenient for you.